# This ID——Community —— approved a pending version indiscreetly in Stackoverflow

Tags: support, suggested-edits, community-user

This is an [Approved record from this ID —— Community](https://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/25136)
The pending version is tangly clearly, but he/her approved it.

Is the ID —— Community a robot of Stackoverflow?

I checked his approved record, and found he had never rejected any pending version.

**Reviewer Stats

Community♦ approved 2172 edit suggestions, and rejected 0 edit suggestions.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Community User - It *is* the robot of StackOverflow.

<s>But looks like someone abused the "Improve" button</s>, because if 2000+ user Improve without touching anything, only "Community User" shown on the edit history.

Comment: Yes, I used "Improve" button, and fixed the tangly content. why Community User approveed more than 2000 pending versions, but nerver rejected any one?

Comment: @Roy, When someone use "Improve" button, Community User accepted it first. But there is no "Reject and Improve" button, so Community User will never rejects anything.

Comment: @Roy, for that edit, you should use reject button, instead of approving it, IMHO.

Comment: Ok, But why the the tangly pending version was approved? I think the robot need to be improved.

Comment: @Roy, may be. If you have better idea, please suggest to them.

Comment: @YOU, OK, I understand. I will reject the tangly version from now on.

Comment: @YOU, I have an idea, may be the robot need to check whether the increased characters are the ture words or phrases.

Comment: Errr, I just [saw](http://i.imgur.com/y2xOG.png) *Community♦ approved 3714 edit suggestions, and rejected 2 edit suggestions.* It's rejecting now too...?

Comment: @Arjan, could be 1) those are from Deleted Users 2) they are testing "Reject and Improve" feature.

Comment: @Arjan, looks like its because of deleted user - http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/6182 - looks like Owner rejected the Jordan's edit and now he is deleted.

Comment: Okay, earlier I went all the way back in Community's activity, from today to the posting date of this very question, and did not see any rejections there. But true, this dates back to February 16th, and it's the very first (listed) review (on the very last page) for Community ;-) Nice find, @YOU!